# I have an Observable object stream and am trying return a Observable<string> stream from an array member

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I need to filter a list of objects and create an distinct observable stream from a string[] member. Typescript 2.9.2

```
interface Product2 {
  id: number;
  categories: string[];
}

const products: Product2[] = [
   {id: 1, categories: ['abc', 'def']},
   {id: 2, categories: ['def', 'xyz']}
];
const products$: Observable<Product2> = from(products);

const allCategories$: Observable<string|void> = products$
  .pipe(
      map((val: Product2) => { from(val.categories).subscribe(); } ),
      distinct()
  );

console.log('logging categories');
allCategories$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Expected 'abc', 'def', 'xyz' got undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` operator requires the inner function to return a value. You're returning `undefined` because you have no `return` statement there.

Anyway, you can use `mergeMap` to unwrap the array of categories into separate emissions then then `distinct()` will do its job:

```
const allCategories$: Observable<string|void> = products$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((val: Product2) => val.categories),
    distinct()
  );
```